# Matplotlib savefig image : improve the quality of output?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I posted sometimes , this kind of image in facebook but I don't know how can I improve the following code , to make sure that all can see and read it correctly :

```
fig ,axes = plt.subplots(ncols=1,nrows=2,constrained_layout=True,figsize=(30,30))

# # ------------------------------Plot first figure --------------------------------------------
palette = ['#F70A0A','#2A930C','#930C85']
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(30,30)},palette= palette, font_scale=1.7)
# # pour les axes 

ax1 = sns.lineplot(x=simple_line_final_df.index,y= 'Totaly olona',data=simple_line_final_df,hue='Madagascar Covid-19',style='Madagascar Covid-19',markers=True,dashes=False,ax=axes[0])

# style 
sns.set_style("darkgrid" , {"ytick.major.size": 10 , "ytick.minor.size": 2 , 'grid.linestyle': '--'})
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('Daty', fontsize = 20)
plt.ylabel('Totaly olona', fontsize = 20)
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#999999', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2 , axis='y')
ax1.set_ylim(0)
last_index = simple_line_final_df.last_valid_index()
ax1.set_xlim(simple_line_final_df.first_valid_index(),simple_line_final_df.last_valid_index())

# -----------------Put annotation ----------
for value in ax1.lines:
    y = value.get_ydata()
    if len(y)>0:
        ax1.annotate(f'{y[-1]:.2f}',xy=(1,y[-1]),xycoords=('axes fraction','data'),ha='left',va='center',color=value.get_color())

#  ------------------------------Plot second figure barplot  --------------------------------------------

sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(30,30)},palette=['#F70A0A','#2A930C','#930C85'], font_scale=1.7)
# pour les axes 
ax = sns.barplot(x=df_final_seaborn.index,y='Isan\'ny olona',data=df_final_seaborn,hue='Covid-19 Madagascar',ax=axes[1])
sns.set_style("darkgrid" , {"ytick.major.size": 10 , "ytick.minor.size": 2 , 'grid.linestyle': '--'})
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('Daty', fontsize = 20)
plt.ylabel('Isan\'ny olona', fontsize = 20)
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#999999', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2 , axis='y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FixedFormatter(df_sea.index.to_series().dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))
for patch in ax.patches:
    x , width , height = patch.get_x(),patch.get_width(),patch.get_height()
    color = patch.get_facecolor()
    #ignore . and nan values 
    if height is None or height ==0:continue
      
    
    ax.text(x+width/2,height+0.1,height.astype(int),ha='center',color=color)

plt.savefig("Sary_finale/04-07-2020 marary_sitrana.jpg" , dpi = 72 , orientation = "landscape")
plt.show()
```

the problem is when I uploaded it on facebook it's difficult for me to see the details .

[image]

I checked here in another question which had the same issue that it's better to save it in .eps but when I change the savefig to :

```
plt.savefig("Sary_finale/04-07-2020 marary_sitrana.eps" , dpi = 72 , orientation = "landscape")
plt.show()
```

I get the message and the result is the same

```
 No handles with labels found to put in legend.
    The PostScript backend does not support transparency; partially transparent artists will be rendered opaque.
```

finally I decided to keep the figsize to figsize=(25,15) and added fontsize=30 in annotate section :

```
# -----------------Put annotation ----------
for value in ax1.lines:
    y = value.get_ydata()
    if len(y)>0:
        ax1.annotate(f'{y[-1]:.2f}',xy=(1,y[-1]),xycoords=('axes fraction','data'),ha='left',va='center',color=value.get_color(),
                    fontsize = 30)
```

Comment: If you want to increase the quality of a graph, use `savefig(filename, dpi=300)`. You can. As a countermeasure for the `eps` error, is 'matplotlib' the latest version?

Comment: I use  matplotlib.__version__ '3.2.1'

Comment: Doesn't `dpi=300` have an effect on JPEG files?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by quality? Is the text too small? Or do you want more resolution/pixels?

Comment: I mean the visibility of the details , if you clicked on  image above , you see that it's difficult to see the number  .

Comment: r-beginners >> I followed your instruction change dpi=300, and save it to .eps  , there is a little improvement

Comment: How about looking at it at even higher resolution? For example, `dpi=450`.

Comment: Your `figsize` is specified as `(30,30)`, i.e. 30x30 inch (76x76 cm). At `fontsize = 20`, your text labels will of course be too small to read. If you want to view the figure online, the default figsize of `(6.4, 4.8)` will yield better results.

Comment: Asmus >> finally I keep figsize to (figsize=(25,15)) but add  fontsize =30 to annotate section